# How to move apps if the option 'move to sd card' is missing?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My android tablet has 4.4.2 kitkat. The option 'move to sd card' is missing from all apps. The internal memory is 2GB and the sd card is 16GB. Is there any way to move apps to sd card? My tablet is rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're rooted, download [Link2sd](https://link2sd.en.uptodown.com/android) and it has an solution for you problem.

Comment: I tried Link2sd but i get this: "App2SD is not supported by your device. Because your device has a primary external storage which is emulated from internal storage."

Answer (score 0):

Hello Android Enthusiasts!

How to move apps if the option 'move to sd card' is missing?

I seem to be having the same issue with my 
Not Rooted: **Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge**

Device Name/Model number: Samsung-SM-G925A 
**Android mobile operating system Version: 5.1.1** 
Linux Kernel version 3.10.61-5927475

I think the 5.1.1 refers to the Android release Lollipop, However the kernel version points toward the KitKat release.

None of my apps seem to have the **Move to SD** option showing either. I've done some research:

I found this info interesting Android OS allows you to move many apps over to external storage to help free up space on the main device. Be aware of the limitations. Some apps are deemed as too important by their developer, and thus can’t be moved via normal methods. Many apps that ship with the device can’t be moved either. Ultimately, it’s up to the app’s developer to allow or disallow its move permissions. and even with the tweaks mentioned on this page (**with the exception of using root**), **the apps still may not be movable afterwards**. Your best bet would be to then email the developer and ask why, or go the way of rooting your device so that you can force it. It shouldn’t be so complicated, but it is.

It needs to be stressed that even if an app (or game) can be moved, there are potential risks for going through with it. Here are some general guidelines of what not to move:

**Apps That Shouldn’t Ever Be Moved**

- List item **Widgets:** If you want to use a certain widget, don’t move the   app that provides it.
- List item **System Tools:** Important tools might not operate well or at all on external storage.
- List item **Important Apps:** If you can’t afford a certain app becoming unavailable, don’t move it.

Consider that to be your first and final warning!

**Things to bear in mind:** Some apps may remain unmovable after these tweaks are applied, which is common of apps that come preinstalled on the device.

In this instance, **the best fix is** to **#1.** root the phone and either delete the app from the system’s ROM with `Titanium Backup`, or **#2.** force the app to be moved with `Link2SD`. Either one of these options is required for Android 5.0 and later. It’s also important to note that even after certain apps are moved, some data is likely required to remain on the internal storage. Don’t consider these tweaks to be miracle solutions.

Guide Index:

Part 1 – Downloading Android’s ‘ADB’

Part 2 – Setting Up Your Phone Or Tablet

Part 3 – Moving Apps On Android 4 & Earlier

Part 4 – Running The Tweak On The Device Itself

Part 5 – Moving Apps On Android 5 & Beyond

> Blockquote

https://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card/

> Blockquote
>                                            ~ Samuel F. Campbell

Comment: Say user1800997 I'm new to this sit. I hope this info is helpful, there seems to be a lot of work to be done, I'm also looking into Using terminal to move applications! I just downloaded a Guide "Linux and Android HOWTO by Guido Gonzato, Ph. D. guido.gonzato at gmail.com The HOWTO provides information on how to manage your Android device using a GNU/Linux system. It's aimed at reasonably competent Linux users who want more control over their Android device. He states in the Requirements:

Comment: He states in the Requirements:  Root permissions are normally forbidden in Android, unless an enlightened vendor decides otherwise.

Comment: To use Link2SD, you must first root your Android device, create an extra partition on your SD card, and download Link2SD from Google Play Store.   https://www.wikihow.tech/Use-Link2SD